# My requirement is to read the data from google spreadsheet, then format (apply some styles) to the data, add some images to the data and fin

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

google app script: I am looking for a customized pdf report using google app script. My requirement is as follows

1. Read data from google spreadsheet (not everything in the spreadsheet, only the required) and display as a table.
2. Prepare the report by merging the above spreadsheet data and some additional data (headers, images).
3. Apply some styles to the data.
4. Add images to the data.
5. Convert into a pdf.

Please help me.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. No one's answered your question so far because it's so broad and doesn't show research. There is plenty of documentation on Google Developers that can help you get started (including quickstart guides you can copy & paste). If you had a specific problem/question about a piece of code, people would be willing to help resolve it. Documentation: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/